# How to make packages cross different Ubuntu release?

Tags: packaging

I'm the author of some software , which depends on libxx6 (In ubuntu 11.10) , but in 12.04 , the package become libxx7 (7 is not a Ubuntu version number) , so the dependency become a problem.

How can i work this out ? I'm managing a PPA , and i want to fix that before release of Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If there is a generic version-free package you can depend on (such as in the Java case: `java-runtime` vs. e.g. `java6-runtime`), depend on that. If there isn't, you have to make specialized packages for the different versions of Ubuntu. Look at the package you depend on's `control` file and see if it `Provides` something more generic you can depend on.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your package will compile against both `libxx6` and `libxx7`, simply us `libxx-dev` in the `Build-Depends` field of you `debian/control` file. Then in the `Depends` field us `${shlibs:Depends}`. This will automatically be substituted with the version of the shared library that your package was built against.

More detailed information about shared libraries can be found in [Chapter 8 of the Debian Policy Manual.](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the same source will build on all the releases, then it's very easy. You build (upload) it separately for each Ubuntu release. You'll have to use slightly different version numbers, I suggest appending `~releasename1`